# Display Google Column Chart with portion of given data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So i'm using Google stacked "Column Chart", given the data:

```
[
['red','green','blue'],
['one', '1','2','3'],
['two', '1','2','3']
['three', '1','2','3']
['four', '1','2','3']
['five', '1','2','3']
]
```

So the scenario is to display only **two**, **three**, **four** on the chart , then whenever user click on **left**/**right** arrows , the data will be shifted left or right.
For example , when user click the left arrow, the chart will display **one**, **two**, **three**

Is there anyway we can achieve this with Google Chart ?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by adding some variables with maxRows and an extra function outside of the drawChart function.

My two left/right buttons looks like this:

```
<input onClick="redrawChart(-1)" type="button" value="<- Left" />
<input onClick="redrawChart(1)" type="button" value="Right ->" />
```

I define a variable as `maxRow` and then return how many rows there are in the dataTable when the function is completed, like

```
chart.draw()
return numberOfRows;
```

my redrawChart function looks liket this:

```
function redrawChart(a) {
    for (i = 0; i < showRows.length; i++) {
        showRows[i] += a
    }
.
.
error checking
.
.
    drawChart(showRows)
}
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/bj3yohs7/5/) and tell me what you think.